# Desktop application using Spring RCP

Tags: java, spring, spring-rcp

I am about to start a project using Spring RCP, which I have no knowledge of.  I was wondering if there was any site where I can learn everything from basic to advanced techniques in this framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with this [introduction](http://www.doclo.be/lieven/SpringRichClient.pdf).
The project has been [renamed to Valkyrie](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?101299-Trying-out-a-new-route...), and it's being developed here: http://www.gitorious.org/valkyrie-rcp

The latest info should be on [this thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?106100-An-update-on-Valkyrie).

Answer (score 0):

You can find open source code of projects written in Spring RCP using [google codesearch](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=%22import+org.springframework.richclient.application.ApplicationLauncher;%22&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

These are the series of tutorials for starting learning how to COde on RCP. It has tutorials for creating a simple project, exporting product, add view, create feature based project, adding logger etc.

[RCP Tutorials - Advanced Tutorials](http://javacodingtutorial.blogspot.de/search/label/RCP)